# Can't get JavaScript to run onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, validation, event-handling

Trying to practice some form validation in the shape of an email reset page.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        form validation
    </title>
    <script>
        function validateForm()
            {
                var email=document.forms["email_reset"]["user_email"].value;
                var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
                var dotpos=email.indexOf(".");
                var pass1=document.getElementByID("new_pwd");
                var pass2=document.getElementByID("confirm_pwd");
                if(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
                    alert("Your email address is invalid!");
                    return false;
                }
                if(pass1 != pass2) {
                    alert("Your passwords do not match!");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Your password has been successfully reset!");
                }
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="email_reset" onsubmit="validateForm()">
        <br />
        <font id="title" face="arial" color="white" size="2">[ Enter your email and new password below ]</font><br /><br />
        <label id="email_lab" color="white">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="user_email" id="user_email" maxlength="100" align="right"  /><br />
        <label id="newpass_lab" color="white">New Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="input" name="new_pwd" id="new_pwd" maxlength="64" align="right"  /><br />
        <label id="confirmpass_lab" color="white">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="input" name="confirm_pwd" id="confirm_pwd" maxlength="64" align="right"  /><br />
        <input style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px;" type="submit" class="input" id="sub_button" value="Submit" /><br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to have an alert pop-up if the email input doesn't match that of an email format, and if the password inputs aren't identically similar. However when I click submit, I get nothing.

I was using [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp) tutorial as a guide. I guess somehow I'm still missing something.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Unexpected displays in PHP or the Javascript console??

Comment: Try: `onsubmit="return validateForm()"`

Comment: No errors. No console output. I'm using Aptana Studio.

Comment: onsubmit="return validateForm()" did not yield an alert either

Answer (score 2):

Error :

> Timestamp: 8/14/2013 11:19:50 AM Error: TypeError:
>   document.getElementByID is not a function Source File:
>   file:///C:/Users/developer/Desktop/tes.html?user_email=asd%40yahoo.com&new_pwd=asd&confirm_pwd=asd
>   Line: 13

Your problem is the function name.

[`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) not `document.getElementByID`

And you should get the value of the HTML element.

```
var pass1=document.getElementById("new_pwd").value;
var pass2=document.getElementById("confirm_pwd").value;
```

Comment: And return the returned value of the function to the handler. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add event to your `validateForm()`, then add a preventDefault

```
function validateForm(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
....
```

Your form is submitting before you hit your validation

------Or-------

Change your submit button to a regular button.

Instead of having an onsubmit on your form have validateForm onClick

On success submit the form

Comment: Thank you. That did not yield an alert.

Comment: "Your form is submitting before you hit your validation" not, it's not. The function has an error and the result of validation is not being returned. Changing to a submit button will not help, nor will calling the function from a button.

Comment: The problem is `getElementById` function. It's should `getElementById` not `getElementByID`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, you need to return false from the listener to prevent submission.

Also, you are comparing two elements (`new_pwd` and `confirm_pwd`) rather than their values. DOM elements are objects, and two objects are never equal.

```
> var pass1=document.getElementByID("new_pwd");
> var pass2=document.getElementByID("confirm_pwd");
> ...
> if(pass1 != pass2) {
```

You might find it easier to use control names rather than IDs for referencing the controls in the form (and you can remove the IDs from the form controls). Also, it's a good idea to pass a reference to the form in the listener, e.g.

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
```

Now the function can be:

```
function validateForm(form) {
    var email = form.user_email.value;
    var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email.indexOf(".");
    var pass1 = form.new_pwd.value;
    var pass2 = form.confirm_pwd.value;
    ...
}
```

The alert for success should be from wherever the form navigates too and should be delivered from the server. Success at the client is very, very different to success at the server.

Comment: It's `getElementById` not `getElementByID`

Comment: Well spotted. But even if fixed, it wont fix the comparison of objects rather than their values. So the OP has 3 major errors — but if form references are used, *getElementById* isn't required. :)